# Crop all written letters from image to form a website

Tags: image-preprocessing

[image]

- Above image has handwritten hindi / deavanagari letters all on a single

  image.
- Task is to Prepare a dataset from the given assignment.jpg image using image

  processing tools
- Idon't have clarity whether i can use photoshop editing tools like adobe photoshop etc.
- If image processing tools mean opencv , is it really possible to create like a emnist like dataset from single image.
- I am not able to come up with any way to seperate the letters from eachother

[image]

Finally i had done it by combining adaptive thresholding,bluring,and morphological, It is helpful to check out [find contours for two part letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183045/finding-contours-of-a-two-part-letter) by @Salman and @Jeru Luke , it really helped me.

Comment: I actually posted it in AI stack overflow, where members suggested i post it here.I don't have any knowledge in domain of computer vision or image processing.Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with OpenCV.

[image]

Code needs to :

1. Prep-process image to enhance contrast
2. Use OpenCV to identify 'bounding box' for each character
3. Save each character's image as a new file

Code example : http://cvisiondemy.com/extract-roi-from-image-with-python-and-opencv/

Comment: Wow ! thanks @Shamit Verma, i actually searched internet for counters code on opencv,thanks for link.

Comment: one last request , could you point me to literature on contours !.I am satisfied with your answer ,i am just stating that me directly learning deep learning have given me surprise that we can do bounding boxes with out advanced techniques!.

Comment: These are useful articles + papers to start in this area : https://towardsdatascience.com/evolution-of-object-detection-and-localization-algorithms-e241021d8bad   , https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-and-instance-segmentation-using-mask-r-cnn-in-opencv-python-c/  , https://eng.ucmerced.edu/people/jyang44/papers/cvpr16_contour_final.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem and cetainly could be solved using any photo editing application like Adobe Photoshop. This would be a lot of manual labour.

But if you want to automate the process of extracting all letters from these image, I would suggest you to use OpenCV and build a **contour detector** and find contours in the image and then crop the contours to extract all the images.

The accuracy of your detector could be improved by converting the image to black and white or binary image or apply some threshold.you can read more about OpenCV contours [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html).
[This blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/24/bank-check-ocr-with-opencv-and-python-part-i/) might also be a little handy.